# Why my program replaces character with 2 spaces?

Tags: c

My Program task is to remove and character <32 and >127 ascii value, but output shows me 2 spaces instead.
Example :

input: préféré

expected output : pr f r

my output       : pr(2spaces)f(2spaces)r(2spaces)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main() {
  unsigned char str[100];
  unsigned char space = ' ';
  fgets(str,100,stdin);
  int i=0;
  int length = strlen(str);
  while(i<length)
  {
    if( ((int)str[i]>32) && ((int)str[i]<127) )
    {
      i++;
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
        str[i]=space;
    }
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: You probably are using UTF-8 which is multi-byte encoding and symbols like é take 2 bytes

Comment: Not what you're asking, but your if condition if wrong. Use >=32 && <=127.

Comment: The output contains spaces in place of certain characters because it explicitly puts them there with `str[i]=space`.  How, then, is this unexpected?

Comment: @JohnBollinger If `é` is considered (by the person doing the expexting) a single character, then two spaces is surprising.

Comment: Dear friend, why do you think that such an easy problem should be here? In the else statement where you got str[i]=space; simply printf %c the value of str[i] before changing it to space and you can decide what to do.

Comment: I get distracted by the `i++;` twice in cooperation with the `continue`.

Comment: @KrassiEm For whoever asks about whatever problem they have, "easy" is never an appropriate description. Even from point of view of the readers (and potential answerers) "easy or not" is not considered a relevant influence on whether or not the question belongs here. Relevant attributes are "clear", "precise", "showing effort", "not been asked and answered already", "not rude". Telling less experienced users that their problems (if matching the relevant attributes) are to easy is not a StackOverflow policy. There is however a "be nice" policy. But printing the replaced chars is a good idea.

Comment: Dear Yunnosch, if at every iteration of the while loop a printf with isascii() is called, it's more helpful than comments on my comment. Needless to say, a for loop without continue is more elegant, however it's also pointless remark. We need to know what locale gives if running Unix-like, and whatever language settings if Windows... Now that an additional function is created to remove the double space makes me laugh and please, don't forget to consider one str[i] =space. That's what counters are for,and the counter can go up and down in value.

Comment: If you would prefer an output like "prefere", you could compute for that. If your source encoding is UTF-8, see the ICU library.

Comment: This is where a `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)` loop is better than a while loop; you'd simplify the loop body to `if (str[i] < 32 || str[i] > 127) str[i] = space;` — two lines instead of ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemingly simple problem gets quite complicated if you want to solve it in  a portable, locale-aware fashion. On the other hand, if the original text is known to be encoded in UTF-8, the solution is quite simple, particularly if you don't need to detect invalid UTF-8 sequences.

The possible values of bytes in UTF-8 encodings fall into four groups:

- single-byte US-ASCII characters: byte values 0x00 through 0x7F, inclusive.
- first byte in a multibyte character: values 0xC2 through 0xF4, inclusive.
- trailing bytes in multibyte characters: values 0x80 through 0xBF, inclusive.
- bytes which cannot appear in any UTF-8 code: everything else (0xC0, 0xC1 and 0xF5 and greater).

Every character therefore contains exactly one byte in the first two sets of values. So a simple strategy is to just delete bytes in the second two sets:

```
unsigned char* out = str;
for (unsigned char* scan = str; *scan; ++scan) {
  if (*scan >= 0x20 && *scan < 0x7F) {
    // Pass through printable ascii characters
    *out++ = *scan;
  }
  else if (*scan < 0x80 || (*scan >= 0xC2 && *scan <= 0xF4)) {
    // Replace non-printable ascii characters and lead UTF-8 bytes with space
    *out++ = ' ';
  }
  // Anything else is ignored and will be overwritten.
}
*out = 0;
```

I deleted the supposedly standards-compliant portable code from this answer because it is simply too complicated, and the resulting code is unlikely to be applicable. In general, input to a utility is not guaranteed to conform to the current locale's multibyte encoding: for example, it is at least conceivable that the input is a vector of `wchar`s (for example, a file encoded in UTF-32 on a system with 32-bit `wchar`). Or that the input is indeed in UTF-8, but the current locale is ISO-8859-7, which is a single-byte encoding. There is no general portable way to convert a `wchar` (or a multibyte sequence) to "Ascii" in order to test whether a given character is one of the ASCII printable characters in code range 0x20 through 0x7F. (And if this paragraph appears to be unintelligible jargon, that will help explain why it was difficult to write and document a portable solution.)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because the characters like `é` (non-ASCII) take up 2 bytes. So your loop runs twice for each `é`, thus putting 2 spaces in place of `é`.

On a related note, use `isascii()` from `<ctype.h>` to test for ASCII characters.

Comment: so do i need to convert 2byte to 1byte,if there is a way?

Comment: @JaspreetSingh Only try to do so if you really need it. It will be non-trivial, because it changes the length of the string and the position inside of any following characters.

Comment: Thank you , i created a function that shifted remaining characters whenever i found 2 consecutive spaces, not best solution but works for now.

Comment: @usr: isascii returns true for a "7-bit US-ASCII character code between 0 and octal 0177 inclusive" whereas the question strongly suggests that the intention is to also replace control characters (codes 0 through 0x1F and 0x7F) with spaces. That could be written as `!isascii(c)||iscntrl(c)`